# CryptographyDeprecationWarning when trying to connect to Mongo Atlas

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, mongoatlas

Getting the below warning when connecting to Mongo Atlas. Though the warning is there connection is successful and able to access the database. I need to know how to get rid of this warning message

```
CryptographyDeprecationWarning: This version of cryptography contains a temporary pyOpenSSL fallback path. Upgrade pyOpenSSL now.
```

I tried updating the pyOpenSSL to the latest version but still getting the warning.